# Изменить размер inline кнопки telegram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Пишу на python с aiogram. Как можно вместить больше текста в одну кнопку, чтобы на мобильном было видно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество столбцов уменьшил до одного, но всё равно мало

```py
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
item1 = InlineKeyboardButton("Копия договора цессии", callback_data='copy_cess')
item2 = InlineKeyboardButton("Уведомление об уступкеправа(требования)", callback_data='notice1')
item3 = InlineKeyboardButton("Справка об отсутствии задолжности", callback_data='ref')
item4 = InlineKeyboardButton("Уведомление об уступке права(требования) и копия договора цессии", callback_data='notice2')
markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)
await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите документ из списка(один)', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Вы можете повлиять на это лишь косвенным образом, к примеру, увеличить размер текстового содержимого сообщения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению, напрямую повлиять на это невозможно

Я бы посоветовал:

1. Убрать деление на два ряда (это даст больше места тексту кнопки)
2. Удлинить текст сообщения

Сделать это можно так (я взял 2 кнопки, для примера, но можно больше):

```
keyboard=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
    text='text_1', callback_data='callback_1')
keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
    text='text_2', callback_data='callback_2')
```

Или так (я предпочитаю этот метод):

```
keyboard = {'inline_keyboard': [
    [{'text': 'text_1', 'callback_data': 'callback_1'}],
    [{'text': 'text_2', 'callback_data': 'callback_2'}],
]}
```